# How to replace the words in string by array

Tags: php

My case:

```
$search  = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$replace = array('B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$subject = 'A and B';
```

i want to change `$subject` to the new string is `B and C`.

i try to use `str_replace($search, $replace, $subject)` but it's returned `F and F`.

How can i do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$result = strtr($subject, array_combine($search, $replace));
```

unlike `str_replace`, `strtr` performs the string in one shot and avoid circular replacements.

*(You must understand that for each item in the search array, `str_replace` processes the whole string.)*

Note that for your specific example, you can write:

```
$result = strtr($subject, 'ABCDE', 'BCDEF');
```

`strtr` can be used in two different ways.

Comment: I got it! i have not ever used `strtr` before. Thank you so much!